# How to sort connections in social networking site LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I see a LinkedIn profile site by default shows the connections sorted by most recent connections. But what if I want to display the first 10 people I connected to? On my LinkedIn profile, first 10-15 connections are the ones I find important to me. My first 10-15 connections are from different areas (University, work, etc.). I do have LinkedIn Premium if that can help.

Comment: Well, your oldest connections are at the bottom of that list. I don't know how many you have, but it took me 10-20 sections to scroll to the end of my 250 connections in a Windows browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to sort by the first set of connections.
There are only 3 options:

1. Recently added
2. First name
3. Last name

[image]

That's all